# Why are there no notifications for comments in a question?

Tags: feature-request, questions, comments, notifications

Earlier today, I was going through some of my comments and found out that some users replied in the comments. But I couldn't reply back since there wasn't any notification regarding this, and so I thought the OP had found his answer.

I was wondering why is it so? The OP could largely benefit if there would be something notifying us that he has replied back.

Comment: They probably didn't put a proper @username reply, which is what the system uses to send notifications. Can you link to an example?

Comment: @Bill the Lizard Yes, you are correct. They didn't use proper username reply.